# Is there a way to use Evince to view PDF attachments in Gmail

Tags: firefox, pdf, gmail

I'm back to using Gmail with Firefox and when I click on PDF attachments they are forced open by the Google docs viewer. I would much prefer that it used the default behavior I have set up for Firefox (using Evince and mozplugger).

Is there a way to force gmail to use an alternative to Google docs viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Gmail is designed to open such files with Google Docs and there is no way that can stop it from doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Click **Download**.

   [image: Download link for a PDF attachment in Gmail]
2. If prompted, choose to open the PDF in Evince.

   [image: Open with Document Viewer]